# Changing bitrate on the fly in AVCaptureSession

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming, h.264, rtp, avcapturesession

I developed a fully functional live streaming app on iOS but my biggest issue right now is the Quality of Service. I implemented an RTSP protocol on the phone to send SR packets and handle RR packets for QoS informations. I need to find a way to change the bitrate settings for my stream session on the fly in order to get a smooth stream.

Currently I can set my own custom settings with this method :

```
(AVAssetWriterInput *)assetWriterInputWithMediaType:(NSString *)mediaType outputSettings:(NSDictionary *)outputSettings
```

However, outputSettings is readonly so I need to find a way to deal with it.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *outputSettings
```

I saw that LiVu app can do it, so there should be a way to do it too :)

So is it possible to change the bitrate of an AVCaptureSession without restarting it and configuring a new AVCaptureInput? I saw we can change some defined presets but I want to configure the bitrate with more accuracy.

Comment: Update : We can add/remove new writers in a smooth way with different encoding settings. Problem solved